# Central air conditioning system isn't working

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, thermostat, central-air, troubleshooting

Ok, so I have done all the research I can and nothing is working. About 3 weeks ago my A/C was running fine nice and cold no issues. Came home to a house that was 97 degrees inside and started immediatly looking at stuff and calling friends.

The next day I went outside and the box that connects the A/C unit and inside wires was missing its breaker panel thingy. I replaced the whole box with a GE one that says it can use fuses or not use them model number TF60RCP (Home Depot). I triple checked to make sure it was wired correctly and it is. I flipped every single breaker on and off. The A/C breaker shuts off whatever makes noise in my basement, but the outside system makes no noise at all period and the fan does not spin period.

The batteries in my thermostat are fine.. but I read that if I switch the thermostat to off between heat and cold then switch the other switch from auto to run... and the thing that makes a blowing noise in my basements comes on then maybe my thermostat is bad. I took my thermostat off and it has a black switch on it that says (gas or electric) Tried switching that switch and still nothing. Can someone please help me! :(

Comment: Can you post photos of how your new A/C disconnect and A/C outdoor unit are wired?  Something's probably goofed up there...

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?  Are you comfortable working on electrical equipment? If you answer no to either of these questions, you should probably contact a professional.

Answer (score 3):

If you can verify that there is power to the condensing unit (outside unit) then you have done all most homeowners can do.

The fan on your furnace (the thing in the basement) will come on any time the A/C is turned on. The outside unit has many safety and will not come on if any of those are not on. For instance, if your system has lost refrigerant over the years and the pressure drops below a certain point if will not come on.

Troubleshooting beyond getting power to the unit is probably something for a professional HVAC technician. Call a reputable one and make sure they give you an estimate of the charges before running up a bill.

Good luck!